# PHP change email address on account when logged in

Tags: php

I am trying to enable a user to change their password on their account when logged in. However, I cant seem to get it to work.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submitEmail'])
{

 $newemail = $_POST['email'];
 $newemail = stripslashes($newemail);
 $newemail = str_replace("'", "&#39", "$newemail");

  //checks database to see if email user types in already exists
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$newemail'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
$nums = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if ($nums >= 1)
 {
  //if email already exists, inform user
 echo "Email already exists";
 echo "<br/>Click <a href = 'account.php?page=email'> HERE</a> to try again";
 }

else
{

//if email does not already exist, update users email
   $querychange = "UPDATE users SET email = '$newemail' where id = '$userID'"; 
   $result3 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $querychange); 

   echo "Your Email has been changed";
   }

}


  else {

  echo "<strong> Current Email: </strong>$email ";
  ?>

    <!-- Allows users to enter new email address -->
    <form name="changeEmail" id="changeEmail" method="post" action="account.php?page=email">
        <input type="hidden" value="email" name="account_submit_type"/>
        <input type='hidden' name='changeEmail' value='yes'>
        <strong> Email </strong><input type = "text" name = "email" size="40" value=""> <br>
        <input type ="button" value="submitEmail" onclick="verifyForm()"/>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have error logging turned on, and do you recieve any errors? What output do you get. Is it writing that your email has been changed or not?

Comment: nothing happens when the submit button is clicked. I have also checked the database and no change in the field

Comment: Can you verify that `$_POST['submitEmail']` has a value when the form is submitted?

Comment: `where id = '$userID'`.. I don't see `$userID` defined here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type ="button" value="submitEmail" onclick="verifyForm()"/>
```

This has to be

```
<input type="submit" value="submitEmail"/>
```

Another error: Undefined $email:

```
echo "<strong> Current Email: </strong>"; echo $email;
```

has to be like this:

```
echo "<strong> Current Email: </strong>"; echo $_POST['email'];
```

Full version which works for me:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submitEmail'])
{

    $newemail = $_POST['email'];
    $newemail = stripslashes($newemail);
    $newemail = str_replace("'", "&#39", "$newemail");

    //checks database to see if email user types in already exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$newemail'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($nums >= 1)
    {
        //if email already exists, inform user
        echo "Email already exists";
        echo "<br/>Click <a href = 'account.php?page=email'> HERE</a> to try again";
    }

    else
    {

        //if email does not already exist, update users email
        $querychange = "UPDATE users SET email = '$newemail' where id = '$userID'";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($db_connection, $querychange);

        echo "Your Email has been changed";
    }

}


else {

    echo "<strong> Current Email: </strong>"; echo $_POST['email'];
    ?>

    <!-- Allows users to enter new email address -->
    <form name="changeEmail" id="changeEmail" method="post" action="#?page=email">
        <input type="hidden" value="email" name="account_submit_type"/>
        <input type='hidden' name='changeEmail' value='yes'>
        <strong> Email </strong><input type = "text" name = "email" size="40" value=""> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submitEmail"/>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Did this help you? If yes, remember to approve this answer, so other people can utilize this thread, when they have the same problem as you have.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. This is working, however it doesnt update the email field in the database

Comment: Compare your column names with these, given in the query   $querychange = "UPDATE users SET email = '$newemail' where id = '$userID'";

Comment: For example: $userID is undefined here! :)

Comment: my field names match yours, but still having no luck

Comment: again: $userID is undefined here in your where clause

Comment: Your query is like: [SELECT FIELDS WHERE ID = ]

Comment: userID is my session variable, do i still need to define it as a variable on this page?

Comment: You access it wrong =) It is $_SESSION['userID'] then.

Comment: Use var_dump(xxx); to check if variables have the value you want. For example: var_dump($_SESSION['userID'];

Comment: Or you can use $userID = $_SESSION['userID']